# iOS ReplayKit locks screen rotation and prevents auto-roatation of iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, swift, screen-rotation, replaykit

I experience a weird issue when working with Replay Kit. Specifically, when I call `startCapture`, the app no longer responds to rotations. It locks the current orientation

```
RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture(handler: { [weak self] (sampleBuffer, sampleBufferType, error) in
        guard sampleBufferType == .video else { return }
        ...
        // Processing the buffer frame here   
}
```

I defined all the orientation in .plist as usual:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

After the ReplayKit is stopped, app starts rotating again fine. iOS version seems has nothing to do with that. Tried on 14, 15.

Any ideas why that happens?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a reason why it does not rotate?